# Serial Communication between 2 Arduinos for analogRead value

Tags: serial, communication, serial-data

I have an optical sensor connected to A0 on Arduino #1 (Nano) giving me values from 200 to 1010. I need to receive these values in Arduino #2 (Nano) through serial communication. I have used a simple code for sending and receiving bytes, but I don't understand how to get the actual sensor values as int. I found some examples showing single values, but as far as I can understand variable values are more complex.

**Transmitter Code:**

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
}
```

**Receiver Code:**

```cpp
void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        int incomingByte = Serial.read();
        Serial.print("I received: ");
        Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should slow down the serial printing on the transmitter side. The Arduino will pretty fast fill up the whole buffer and every serial write with a full buffer will result in values, that do not get transmitted. That might also be the problem with Rudy's answer. Try adding a short `delay(100);`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to get familiar with the standard C function sscanf().  It does exactly what you're looking for, converts an ASCII string into whatever type you like.

[sscanf() API](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)

The code to read an integer from the serial port would look something like this:

```
  char recv_buf[10];  int recv_int;
  Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', recv_buf, 9);
  recv_buf[9] = 0;  // make sure it's null terminated
  sscanf(recv_buf, "%d", &recv_int);
  Serial.print("I received: ");
  Serial.println(recv_int);
```

Answer (score 1):

One byte is 8 bits so 2^8 is equal to 255. One byte can hold value up to 255. Since you have value of 1023(max possible) you have to split value into two bytes.
Here's an example:

```
unsigned byte highValueByte(int value)
{
    return (value >> 8);
}

unsigned byte lowValueByte(int value)
{
    return (value - (highValueByte(value) << 8));
}

int giveValue(unsigned byte highByte, unsigned byte lowByte)
{
    return ((highByte << 0) & 0xFF) + ((lowByte << 8) & 0xFFFF);
}



void loop()
{
    int senValue = analogRead(/* PIN NUMBER */);
    int byteOne = highValueByte(senValue);
    senValue = lowValueByte(senValue);
}
```

Your code Works for one byte(try it), but it doesn't for two bytes value. Because you have two bytes, you have to introduce some kind of buffer.
Example:
`unsigned byte buffer[2] = { 0, 0 };`
Also be sure you connected pins properly. RX from Arduino #1 goes into TX from Arduino #2 and vice versa.

[About serial communation sync](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=445518.0)